# shell script to execute rails runner via cron with rvm

Tags: bash, cron, rvm, runner

In `crontab` I have:

```
0,30 * * * * sh /path/to/my/script.sh
```

and in my `script.sh` I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
rvm use 1.9.2@r321
cd /path/to/my/proyect
rails runner rails_script.rb
```

But it doesn't load the `rvm` in `1.9.2`, It stays on the system setting which is `1.8.7` in my case.

What should I do to make sure the runner is running under `rvm` in `1.9.2` with the gemset `r321`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are at least 4 ways to make cron working with RVM: https://rvm.io/integration/cron/

personally I prefer the `2. Loading RVM environment files in shell scripts.`

Comment: Well when I run `$ rvm env --path -- 1.9.2@r321` it returns `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p290@r321` then I edit my script and add `source /home/ubuntu/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p290@r321` but when I run the script it says: `source: not found`, any idea why?

Comment: Yes, the file `ruby-1.9.2-p290@r321` is located under `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/environments/`

Comment: is it the same machine ? copy-paste that line into your terminal and check if it changes `rvm current`

Comment: Yes it is in the same machine, now if I try tu run the script with `sh /path/to/script.sh` gives me the error, but if i run this with `./path/to/script.sh` works perfectly. what's up with that?

Comment: sh is limited shell, run it with bash/zsh

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is:  RVM worked only correct in your user shell.  Remember  after
installing rvm you must write somethink like.

> '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

in your .zshrc or .bashrc

Tell cron with wich user you use rvm because rvm must load as a function 
and with a user that not load rvm as a function it will not worked and the system ruby version  is used automatically.
Example:

> 0,30 * * * *  USERNAME  bash /path/to/my/script.sh

alternativly you can install rvm as multiuser show at: [enter link description here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)